# IFrame does not work for local sources? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

Does IFrame works for local directory? I'm trying to embed excel into my HTML but nothing shows up. I have tried many ways to put in my local directory but it remains the same.

```
<iframe src="file://C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\hi.xls" width="98" height="120" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The end result have been an empty box.

Comment: Don't use local path when you create any web application..

Comment: @AnantDabhi Just trying to test it out whether it works.

Comment: better place your file in the same folder and just give the path from that folder........... suppose like........................ `<iframe src="files/hi.xls">`... It would be better than giving all the path from `C:\Documents and Settings........................`

Comment: @annampriyatam I have to use the full directory because of the development at the later stage. Using ColdFusion, I'm actually storing the excel files in GetTempDirectory(), a coldfusion function which returns the full directory path.

Comment: oh okk.. then i think may be due to the slashes.. Here you have  `//` in `file://` and in the rest of the path you have \.. am not sure that it'll work.. but just give a try...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't add I-frame with local file `src`
All modern browsers prevent display of "local" files using the file protocol in `iframes` for security reasons.

check your browser console... 
if you get message like it means your browser prevent load local resource to `Iframe`

**Not allowed to load local resource**

[image]

Comment: So is it not possible to load the full local path of the file?

Comment: Sort of. I made a symlink in public_html to a local documents directory, '.../docs/html' as 'docs', and used `src='docs/index.html'`, and got what I wanted. I'm not sure if this is a good idea in general, so if you're going to do it anyway, make sure only you can reach it.